# scp error al enviar archivo con letras especiales

Tags: linux

FORTIFY: vsnprintf: size 18446744073709551615 > SSIZE_MAX

¿Cómo modifico estas letras   y las hago normales, así: Dragon Ball? que se encuentran en un archivo llamado scpssh.sh ya que el comando scp arroja error al enviar ese archivo que pesa solo 3mb.

Este es mi código:

```
cd /sdcard/

find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname " .mp4" | cut -c 3- > scpssh.sh 

home=$(cat scpssh.sh) 

scp -P 22 $home pc@ip:
```

Comment: Si haces `ls -al` en el directorio donde está el mp4, cómo se ve el nombre del archivo?

Comment: -rwxrwx--- 1 root everybody  4037404 Dec 18  2020 ' .mp4'*

Comment: sed 's//d/g; s//r/g; s//a/g; s//g/g; s//o/g; s//n/g; s//l/g; s//b/g; s//g/g; s//t/g' scpssh.sh

Comment: esto que pones en los comentarios, ¿qué es? Recuerda que si estás intentando cosas nuevas, puede [edit] la respuesta que el código en los comentarios es ilegible. Si quieres compartir la solución que tú mismo hallaste, usa el campo de abajo que se titula Tu Respuesta. Podrás recibir votos positivos y aceptarla como solución en unas horas

Answer (score 0):

esta fue mi solución

nl=$(grep -Eino "|||s||||" scpssh.sh | tail -n 1)

nl=$(echo "${nl%:*}")

narc=$(sed -n "${nl}p" scpssh.sh)

le=$(grep -Eio "|||||||||" scpssh.sh | tail -n 1)

if [[ "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" || "$le" == "" ]]; then

sed -i 's//d/g; s//r/g; s//a/g; s//g/g; s//o/g; s//n/g; s//l/g; s//b/g; s//g/g; s//t/g' scpssh.sh

narcn=$(sed -n "${nl}p" scpssh.sh)

mv "$narc" "$narcn"

fi